# Unexpected character '#' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | #!/usr/bin/env node

Tags: npm, webpack, package.json, babel-loader

I have a react boilerplate app with webpack 5.3.2
I am using `babel-loader` as well as `shebang-loader` together. Below is my configuration.

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/, // Transform all .js files required somewhere with Babel
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: options.babelQuery,
    },
    {
      loader: 'shebang-loader'
    }],
  }
],
```

And when i run `npm run build:dll` i am getting the below issue

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
Module parse failed: /..../.../.../modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js 
Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| #!/usr/bin/env node
| ;(function () { // wrapper in case we're in module_context mode
|   // windows: running "npm blah" in this folder will invoke WSH, not node.
 @ ./node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js 484:4-32
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps
```

even using the `shebang-loader` results in showing up the above issue. Really appreciate for the help here.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the exclude line from your webpack config?

Comment: @dwjohnston did just now. Getting  `Couldn't find preset "es2015"` issue. does it mean have to go install `babel-preset-es2015`? And that's one of the issue. There are multiple other issues like `Unknown plugin "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties" `